# MongoDB: Why am I getting "ReferenceError: restaurants_db is not defined"?

Tags: mongodb, api

I'm using MongoDB to store data from an API and whenever I try to add the API data into the database I get "[thread1] ReferenceError: restaurants_db is not defined"

Here's what I input in terminal, using the mongo shell:

use restaurants_db

```
"Switched to db restaurants_db"
```

show collections

```
"restaurants"
"restaurantsVisited"
```

restaurants_db < restaurantAPI.js

```
[thread1] ReferenceError: restaurants_db is not defined
```

Any idea what's wrong and how I can fix it?

Here's my API:

```
use restaurants_db;

db.restaurants.insert([
{
name: "Amarone",
coords: [55.9537467, -3.1944039],
},
{
name: "McDonalds",
coords: [55.9538144,-3.1928817],
},
{
name: "Pizza Hut"
coords: [55.9535647,-3.1978135],
},

]);
```

Comment: Did you enter `restaurants_db < restaurantAPI.js` into the `mongo` shell? The `mongo` shell is a Javascript-oriented shell and doesn't understand UNIX-style redirects. What are you trying to achieve, and what are the contents of the `restaurantAPI.js` file?

Comment: I worked it out: as you say, entering `restaurants_db < restaurantAPI.js` into the `mongo` shell isn't even a thing. I needed to do it outside the shell, just as a normal UNIX command. The intention was to add my API to my database.